# Unlocalized text when signing up for ja.SO

Tags: bug, status-completed, localization

When creating an account at ja.SO using my regular SE login, the following appears:

[image: creating a ja.SO account]

The text "You are about..." is not localized to Japanese.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will be fixed next build. For localization issues, it's best to ask on [meta.ja.stackoverflow.com](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/) where I'll be more likely to see it.